# Kubuntu 21.10 install stuck at confirmation of what system to install

Tags: kubuntu

I am trying to install Kubuntu 21.10 on my computer. Unfortunately, I can only get to the installer. I am running the ISO on Ventoy, and on the trial part of the installer, it is already unable to see the internal drive. However, in the installer, it just gets stuck trying to load the disks selection part of the install. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Kubuntu 21.04 is has reached end of support. Try 21.10 instead.

Comment: As above. Either use 21.10, 20.04 or wait for the release of 22.04, the next LTS. N.B. - You're likely to face the same issue so you need to check the drive mode in UEFI: It must be set to AHCI. "RAID", Intel RST, etc. are not yet supported. Keep in mind that if you intend to dual-boot with a previously installed Windows you need to install AHCI support in Windows before changing the drive mode.

Comment: @guiverc sorry I changed to the correct version number, however I did use the last LTS and same issue occurred